# Sci fi novel. Birds fall from the sky, gravity seems to be changing

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book where a young girl and her friend are experiencing birds falling down on the ground, and gravity no longer seeming to be the same. Everything in their short lives is changing. It's the description of how one may feel when everything one thought was eternal is falling apart.

It is not an Anders book. It's some years ago I read it and loaned it, never got it back. I think it is an female American writer.

---

It is a novel about a situation where gravity no longer is exactly the same as it used to be. The consequence is that birds are falling to the ground. A girl is the protagonist and it concerns how she feels about the scary news which the media is spreading all over. Normal life is falling apart piece by piece.

In technical terms, the novel is not spectacular, nor is there some hero who is rescuing the society. It is more a description of the psychological effects, the daily life where security which is no longer guaranteed. The girl has to go to school of course. But also this duty is over. It gives a sensation of getting lost.--- Does my description help?

Comment: Can you think of any other details? When did you read this for example?

Comment: Have a read through the checklists at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question). I'm sure you can come up with more info for us.

Comment: Sounds like The Core, although that's a movie...

Comment: Why did you edit *out* the extra details that I put in from your deleted (non-)answer?

Comment: Sorry, I am not used yet to your way of exchanging informations. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [The Age of Miracles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Age_of_Miracles) by Karen Thompson Walker, who is [American](http://www.theageofmiraclesbook.com/author/).  From a review on Gizmodo, "[The Most Overhyped Science Fiction Novel of the Year?](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5940712/the-most-overhyped-science-fiction-novel-of-the-year)":

> The rotation of the Earth slows down, and pretty much overnight, one
>   day is 25 hours. Within a short time, the days get longer and longer.
>   So by the time you're a ways into the book, a day is 48 hours long,
>   meaning that there are 24 hours of sunlight and around 24 hours of
>   darkness. Meanwhile, gravity gets heavier for some reason, so all the
>   birds fall out of the sky and die, and there are plagues of insects
>   that the birds no longer eat.

The review also mentions that the main character is a girl who goes to school and agrees with your judgement that it's "not a terrible book. Just very mediocre."

Comment: Exactly! It is the novel I am looking for. Read it and never forget it. Thank you panacebo!